# Setting numlock on Raspberry Pi always on

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I'm trying to set <kbd>numlock</kbd> to be always on for my numpad on my Raspberry Pi, how do I make this possible?

```
$ sudo sed -i 's/#LEDS=+num/LEDS=+num/' '/etc/kbd/config'
```

Using the code above in the terminal I was able to make it boot with the LED on, but it can't be turned off after hitting the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Using the code above in command line I turned made it boot with it on, but it can be turned off after hitting the button

This isn't exactly a way to keep it on directly, but it is a way to disable it completely so if it is already on it can't be turned off.

This only works in an X server setting (i.e., with the GUI desktop). First:

```
xev -event keyboard
```

A little white window with a black square in it should appear.  You can ignore that.  Hit <kbd>NumLock</kbd> and you should get a report like this:

```
KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x7400001,
    root 0x13d, subw 0x0, time 60300645, (1159,-112), root:(1159,706),
    state 0x2, keycode 38 (keysym 0x41, A), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (41) "A"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (41) "A"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x7400001,
    root 0x13d, subw 0x0, time 60300725, (1159,-112), root:(1159,706),
    state 0x2, keycode 38 (keysym 0x41, A), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (41) "A"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Actually, that's for <kbd>a</kbd>; I don't have a NumLock on this keyboard.  Every time you press a key you will get a "KeyPress event" and a "KeyRelease event". Note before this there's probably a "KeyRelease" for the Return at the end of the command. *Don't move the mouse or you may loose the functionality.*

For both events, the third line with "(keysym ____, ____)" should mention `Num_Lock`.  Notice right before that it says, most likely, "keycode 77". ("a" above is 38). The number may be different; this is the information you want.

You can stop `xev` by closing the little white window with the mouse.

Now:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 77 = NoSymbol'
```

Where `77` is the keycode you got. You can put that in whatever GUI start-up script is appropriate; that should run *after* the X server starts.

You can enable it again:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 77 = Num_Lock'
```

Comment: For some reason when this code is run we can't drag the window, close windows, minimize or maximize windows

Comment: Which code? `xev` or `xmodmap`?